# How to delete only the relation in a many to many relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have the following three tables:

```
player (id, name)
status (id, status_text)
player_status (player_id, status_id)
```

The player_status table combines the first two tables with a n-to-n relationship

Table "**player**":

| id | player |
| --- | --- |
| agzua76t34gusad | "Anna" |
| sdahb433tbjsdbv | "Julia" |

Table "**status**":

| id | status_text |
| --- | --- |
| jjbsdnv8677v6df | "operational" |
| bulsiu783fdszjh | "violated" |

Table "**player_status**"

| record_id | record_status_id |
| --- | --- |
| agzua76t34gusad | jjbsdnv8677v6df |
| sdahb433tbjsdbv | bulsiu783fdszjh |

The player can have a status assigned or not.
Now when a player has a status, how can I remove this status, so that the player but also the status stays in the tables but only the relation in the `player_status` table will be removed.

These are the classes for Player and Status

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "player")
public class Player {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
        })
    @JoinTable(name = "player_status",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "player_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "status_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<Status> statusList = new HashSet<>();
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "status")
public class Status {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "status_text", nullable = false)
    private String statusText;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
        }, mappedBy = "statusList")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Player> players = new HashSet<>();
}
```

This is how the relation table is created in `*.sql`:

```
create table player_status
(
    player_id varchar references player (id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
    status_id varchar references status (id) on update cascade
);
```

How can I delete only an entry from the player_status table? I tried to retrieve a player from the db, changed/removed his status, but this did not update the player.

Comment: you need to create a relation entity.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many

Comment: So there it is point 3. Many-to-Many Using a Composite Key which I have to implement?

Comment: So, yes, that's what I was thinking. But, I don't know why you cannot delete the relation without a a seperate jpa entity.

Comment: But the separate repository did the trick. I can now remove and add more easily. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure, it could probably be more efficient if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You just remove the associated `Status` from the `statusList` collection, and the row of the association table will be automatically deleted when the `EntityManager` is flushed.